# C++ calculate distance between structure of inputed and saved points and the origin, print out list according on distance

Tags: c++

In this task a simplified version of obstacles shall be modeled by points detected by an imaginary sensor system placed in the origin of a two dimensional local cartesian coordinate system.
Arbitrary many of such obstacles /points in front of a vehicle shall be possible to store in a list. This list shall be sorted by the Euclidian distance from the origin (see examples below).
(Hint: write a function to calculate the Euclidian distance d of two obstacles/points P1 and P2 with coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) by the formula: d=√(x1−x2)2+(y1−y2)2
To simply identify them each obstacle/point shall store a string ("A", "B", ... in example above), the distance and its coordinates (xi,yi). 
(Hint: give a type definition for a structure with these four data as components/variables of the structure.)
In a loop in function main arbitrary many of such obstacles/points shall be possible to be inputted and stored in a list. Afterwards the sorted by distance list shall be outputted. Beside the string, distance and coordinates in each output also the string of the nearest obstacle/point to it shall be computed and outputted additionaly (see example below).
(Hint: write a further function with a list of all obstacles/points as first and one obstacle/point as second parameter calculating the neareast other obstacle/point to it and returning it as pointer. Take care that an obstacle/point does not return and output distance 0 to itself, and that at least two obstacles/points need to exist; otherwise a null pointer nullptr shall be returned.)

I was able to create the structure function, the distance function and the list, unfortunately I'm not able to sort it and to use the function distance to calculate the actual distances.

Hope someone can help me!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double distanceCalculate(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
{
    double x = x1-x2;
    double y = y1-y2;
    double dist;
    dist = pow(x, 2) + pow(y , 2);
    dist = sqrt(dist);
    return dist;
}

struct point
{
    char name [1];
    double x, y, origin_distance ;
    struct point *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    struct point *head = nullptr, *newElement, *p ;
    do
    {
        cout << "0 end"<< endl;
        cout <<"1 input point"<< endl;
        cout <<"2 print list of points" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)

        {
        case 1:
            newElement = new point;
            if (newElement == nullptr)
                cerr << "Not enough free memory " << endl;
            else
            {
                cout<< "Please enter point's name: ";
                cin>> newElement ->name;
                cout << "Please input value x:";
                cin >> newElement->x;
                cout <<"Please input value y:";
                cin >> newElement->y;
                newElement ->next = head;
                head = newElement;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<< "Print list of points"<< endl;
            cout<< "name.\t x.\t y.\t" << endl;
            p=head;
            while (p!= nullptr)
            {
                cout<< p->name<<"\t"<< p->x<<"\t" << p->y << "\t" << endl;
                p=p->next;
            }
            break;


        }
    } while (choice !=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char name[1]` is *very* bad. In C++ char arrays must be `'\0'` terminated. You have not allocated space for that. Use a `strings instead.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays, i can just create a structure where the points should be saved..

Comment: @Oana - you're using an array to store the name. The array is too short to hold anything other than a null-terminator. You should use the std::string type.

Comment: You *are* using an array for your point name. That's the problem, use a `char name` if you like. but do *not* use `char name[1]`.

Comment: @JonathanMee - you mean a `char *name`? A `char name` has the same storage capacity as `char name[1]`

Comment: @enhzflep I do not. I mean a `char name`. `cin` will correctly read one character when streaming into a `char`, It will read a string when streaming into a `char[]` if the OP want's to use a single character as the name of the node doing `char name` is fine.

Comment: @Oana Aside from the problem with your `name` member, you never populate `origin_distance` and you never try to use it, have you tired to do anything with this in your code? If so please show us your work?

Comment: @JonathanMee I've updated the question and added a detailed description of the task.

Comment: @JonathanMee Untill now all what my programm does is saving a list of points, but unfortunatelly I'm not able to calculate the distance or sort anything, I'm new to C++ so I don't have so many experience

Comment: @Oana There may be someone on here who will write your code for you, but I'd prefer to work with you to help you understand. You're description of the homework is a far cry from where you are. Why don't you start by adding a sample input and output and tell us what operations you want to perform to reach the output.

Comment: @JonathanMee I seriously wasn't looking for someone to write my code, I want to understand how to do it, beause there are going to be more of them.. Unfortunatelly after I create the distance function and the srtucture for storing the list, I don't know how to use the function distance to calculate the distance between the points.. I would be way happier if you could help me understand and not just write the code for me..

Comment: Small note.  Euclidean distance uses the absolute value of `x1-x2` and `y1-y2`  so more like this `abs(x1-x2)`

Comment: @NathanielJohnson The immediately following square operation will take care of that. I would go as far as to say that the use of an `abs` call here is wasteful and bad code.

Comment: @Oana Let's use the simplest possible case, say you have 2 `points`: `const point first{ '\0', 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, nullptr }, second{ '\0', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, nullptr }` What can you do to find the distance between `first` and `second`?

Comment: @JonathanMee  Taken in consideration the function I wrote up and that points first and second are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) i would say: int main() { double x1, y1, x2, y2; double dist; cout << "Enter x1:" << endl; cin >> x1; cout << "Enter y1:" << endl; cin >> y1; cout << "Enter x2:" << endl; cin >> x2; cout << "Enter y2:" << endl; cin >> y2; dist = distanceCalculate(x2, y2); cout << "Distance Between (" << x2 << " , " << y2 << ") and (" << x1 << " , " << y1 << ") = " << dist; }

Comment: @Oana Your statement reveals a misconception: `dist = distanceCalculate(x2, y2)` `distanceCalculate` takes 4 arguments, you pass 2. this won't work. How would `distanceCalculate` know where the other point is? Also, I want to see you find the distance between `first` and `second` not a bunch of `doubles`. I've defined them for you so you don't have to populate them with `cin`. I just want you to tell me how you'd find the distance between `first` and `second`.

Comment: @JonathanMee I don't know.. I'm sorry..

Comment: @Oana No worries. We'll start another step removed. Let's not talk programming, let's talk math. If I give you the points (1, 2) and (3, 4) how would you find the distance between them?

Comment: @JonathanMee sqrt(1+3)^2+(2+4)^2..  at least I know something..

Comment: @Oana Well you have a typo, but yeah basically [our equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry) is: *((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)^.5* You can think of this equation as the mathematical version of a function. So let's start by defining that C++ function. What are the inputs it will take and what is the return it will have?

Comment: @JonathanMee
double x1, x2, y1, y2;
double x = x1-x2;
double y = y1-y2;
 double dist;
    dist = pow(x, 2) + pow(y , 2);
    dist = sqrt(dist);
    return dist;

Comment: @Oana Right, but if we talk about the function signature. That'll look something like what you already have: `double distanceCalculate(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)` So now lets take the next step. How would I get the distance between the points (1, 2) and (3, 4) from the function `distanceCalculate`?

Comment: @JonathanMee I should just substitute the values inside the formula, either by input from the user or just from rewriting..

Comment: @Oana Right... so show me the code which would pass those values into `distanceCalculate` and say print the result.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you're mixing the definitions of a point and of a (linked)list node. A more typical implementation would see you defining 2 types - one for the point and another for a list node.
Perhaps something like:

```
typedef struct point
{
 double x, y;
};
typedef struct listNode
{
  point data;
  listNode *next;
};
```

However, reading your question - it doesn't appear that defining a type capable of representing the list was part of your task. As such, you may as well leave it to the std library. I've done that, using the std::vector as the container to hold the list of points.

Not only do you now need only to concern yourself with defining a datatype to hold the 2d point, you also get easy sorting basically for free. You define a function that will return true or false, depending on whether one element should come before the next, or not.

There looks like nothing wrong with your distance function, though I'd avoid using the pow function when squaring - I'd simply use `x*x + y*y`

Another advantage of using the `std::vector` type, is that you can access the elements it contains using standard array notation. With that in mind, to display the nearest and furthest points from the origin, you can sort the list then simply display `pointList[0]` and `pointList[numElements-1]`.

Here's a rough implementation:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct vec2_t
{
    double x;
    double y;
} *pVec2;

typedef std::vector<vec2_t> vecVectors;
typedef vecVectors::iterator vecVectorsIter;

double distBetween(vec2_t &p1, vec2_t &p2)
{
    double dx = p1.x - p2.x, dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    return sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
bool orderPointAsc(vec2_t &p1, vec2_t &p2)
{
    vec2_t origin = {0.0,0.0};
    return (distBetween(origin,p1) < distBetween(origin,p2));
}

int main()
{
    vecVectors pointList;
    vec2_t origin = {0.0, 0.0};
    int i, n=10;

    vec2_t tmp;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp.x = 100 * (rand() % 0xFFFF) / 65535.0;
        tmp.y = 100 * (rand() % 0xFFFF) / 65535.0;
        pointList.push_back(tmp);
        printf("%d. - <%5.02f, %5.02f> - dist from origin: %0.02f\n", i, tmp.x, tmp.y, distBetween(origin, tmp));
    }
    printf("Sorting...\n");
    std::sort(pointList.begin(), pointList.end(), orderPointAsc);
    for (vecVectorsIter iter = pointList.begin(); iter!=pointList.end(); iter++)
    {
        printf("<%5.02f, %5.02f> - %5.02f\n", (*iter).x, (*iter).y, distBetween(origin, (*iter)) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample output

```
0. - < 0.06, 28.18> - dist from origin: 28.18
1. - < 9.67, 40.44> - dist from origin: 41.58
2. - <29.25, 23.99> - dist from origin: 37.83
3. - <17.51, 44.80> - dist from origin: 48.10
4. - <41.14, 37.33> - dist from origin: 55.55
5. - < 8.71, 42.95> - dist from origin: 43.82
6. - <35.52, 25.68> - dist from origin: 43.83
7. - <15.20,  0.75> - dist from origin: 15.22
8. - < 4.57, 18.22> - dist from origin: 18.79
9. - < 7.37,  8.29> - dist from origin: 11.09
Sorting...
< 7.37,  8.29> - 11.09
<15.20,  0.75> - 15.22
< 4.57, 18.22> - 18.79
< 0.06, 28.18> - 28.18
<29.25, 23.99> - 37.83
< 9.67, 40.44> - 41.58
< 8.71, 42.95> - 43.82
<35.52, 25.68> - 43.83
<17.51, 44.80> - 48.10
<41.14, 37.33> - 55.55
```

Comment: I've updated my question and wrote a better description of the homework. Unfortunatelly I'm new to programming and to C++ that's why I made so many mistakes, in my code I should be using pointers, and create functions outside the main function that I can use inside it for example to calculate the distance and create a list of points..

Comment: I've included a function useful for calculating the distance - it performs the same task yours does. I've not used pointers, since I didn't know their use to be a requirement. Though, the code does demonstrate a method to create a list of points, get their individual distances from the origin and finally, sort this list of points based on this distance. You'd need to use user input, rather than `rand()` for the point locations.